# Apostrophe in String to Blob conversion, unexpected Output:<p> I don&#39;t go to school </p>

Tags: apex, blob

> Input: Content__c = `I don't go to school`
> Output: `<p>I don&#39;t go to school</p>`

If I remove apostrophe, input and output are same as expected without p tags. Please refer the below code:

```
List<TEX_Notes_Staging__c> texNoteList = [select Id, Guest_Id__c, Status__c, Processed__c, Content__c, VIN__c, Guest_Name__c, Dealer_Code__c, Dealer_Name__c, TEX_Hub_Time_Stamp__c, Opportunity_Id__c, Title__c, Notes_Body__c from TEX_Notes_Staging__c where id = 'a399n000000727PAAQ'];

ContentNote nt = new ContentNote();
String texContent = texNoteList[0].Content__c;
nt.Title = texNoteList[0].Title__c;
String decode = texContent.unescapeHtml4();
nt.Content = Blob.valueOf(decode);
insert nt;

ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdl.ContentDocumentId = nt.Id;
cdl.LinkedEntityId = texNoteList[0].Opportunity_Id__c;
cdl.ShareType = 'V';
cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert cdl;
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong.